# How to add string values in modal using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have (3)three fields in my modal.. sizes, initial qty, and delivery qty..
what I want is to add the value of the initial and delivery qty..

here is the my modal body..

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <?php for($i=1;$i <= 12;$i++): ?>
        <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            <label for="size<?=$i;?>">Size:</label>
            <input type="text" name="size<?=$i;?>" id="size<?=$i;?>" value="<?=((!empty($sArray[$i-1]))?$sArray[$i-1]:'');?>" class="form-control" readonly required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label for="qty<?=$i;?>">Initial Qty:</label>
            <input type="number" name="qty<?=$i;?>" id="qty<?=$i;?>" value="<?=((!empty($qArray[$i-1]))?$qArray[$i-1] +$delqty:'');?>" min="0" class="form-control" readonly required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label for="delqty">Del Qty:</label>
            <input type="number" name="delqty<?=$i;?>" id="delqty<?=$i;?>" min="0" class="form-control" required/>
        </div> 
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="updateSizes();jQuery('#sizesModal').modal('toggle');return false;">Save changes</button>
  </div>
```

and here is the function..

```
function updateSizes(){
    var sizeString = '';
    for(var i=1;i<=12;i++){
        if(jQuery('#size'+i).val() != ''){
            sizeString += jQuery('#size'+i).val()+':'+jQuery('#qty'+i).val()+',';

     //how to add the value of this? "jQuery('#qty'+i).val()" to this "jQuery('#delqty'+i).val()"
        }
    }
    jQuery('#sizes').val(sizeString);
}
```

How can I add those string values?

I tried this and its output is NaNNan..

```
function updateSizes(){
    var sizeString = '';
    for(var i=1;i<=12;i++){
        if(jQuery('#size'+i).val() != ''){
            sizeString += jQuery('#size'+i).val()+':'+parseInt($("#qty").val(), 10)+parseInt($("#delqty").val(), 10)+',';
        }
    }

    jQuery('#sizes').val(sizeString);
}
```

any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap each of the values being added in a parseInt() function.

So it would look like

```
var x = parseInt($("#something1").val(), 10)+parseInt($("#something2").val(), 10);
```

Comment: `Number($("#something1").val())` and `+$("#something1").val()` are also valid string to numeric parse methods. However, it's good practice to specify the radix when using `parseInt`

Comment: like this? sizeString += jQuery('#size'+i).val()+':'+parseInt($("#qty").val(), 10)+parseInt($("#delqty").val(), 10)+',';